# Detective, what is the password?

Tags: pattern, mystery

The police suspect a teenager named Joe of planning to murder his ex-girlfriend's entire family.  The evidence is locked in Joe's computer.  Failing to hack into the computer, the police find Joe's best friend Billy and gather some information:

1) Joe has put his ex's family members into 2 groups on a whiteboard as below:

Group 1:

```
Father
Sister
Son
Daughter
Children
Cousin
Nancy (her cat)
```

Group 2:

```
Mother
Brother
Boyfriend
Husband
Parent
Sibling
Bobby (her pet snake)
```

2) Joe has used one of his friends' names as the computer's password.  The names are:

- Billy
- Lilly
- Kelly
- Ally
- Nancy

3) Joe has told Billy that his computer's password **shares the same attribute that he used to categorize his ex's family**.

4) A single failed attempt to login to Joe's computer will cause the computer to reformat, thus losing all the evidence.

It turns out to be a very simple logic and a smart detective quickly solves it and arrests Joe.  The question is: what is the attribute Joe used to categorize his ex's family, and what is the password?

*EDIT: I should have mentioned that the attribute helps to distinguish the password from the rest of the choice*

Hint #1:

> The Attribute does not necessarily relate to a word's spelling / length.  Even the description of the ex's pet fits into the attribute it shares with the group.

Comment: Sounds like a pretty brutal guy, that Joe ...

Comment: Thanks for the edit @randal'thor!  Haha no offense to anyone named Joe out there!

Comment: What does "shares the same attribute" mean?

Comment: @JackM it means he uses the same method to categorize the family member as to decide his computer's password

Comment: That doesn't make sense - the method used to categorize family members would be something that serves to classify people into two different categories. The method used to choose his computer's password is something that selects a string out of the set of all possible strings. How can they be the same? Do you mean that we know that the categorization method would place the password into a particular group?

Comment: @JackM that's why it is a brainteaser!

Comment: take the hard disk out, put it as slave(not master/not boot disk) to another computer and open all files there. If it still asks for a password, get 5 disks, copy his disk completely on the other ones and try each name on each separate disk. 5 names, 5 attempts, easy! :D

Comment: @Novarg lol, I believe there're many ways to achieve what you're trying to do, but let's assume removing the hard disk / any external plug will also instantly remove the evidence required =D

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The password is

> Billy

My explanation:

> Group 1 is all names/phrases that can be said without completely closing your mouth/touching both of your lips together. Group 2 is all names/phrases where you are required to touch both of your lips together (M in Mother, B in Brother, the middle "b" in Husband, etc.)
> Given this connection, 4 of the 5 names (Lilly, Kelly, Ally, Nancy) match Group 1, while Billy is the only one that matches Group 2. Therefore, being the outlier, Billy must be the password.

Comment: Grrr, I was just typing out this exact answer when your one appeared! +1. The only slight problem is the hint, which mentions that even the pets' descriptions fit. "Cat" fits, and "pet snake" fits, but "snake" by itself doesn't.

Comment: Nicely done!  Also @BenM, the hint mention the 'description' not the name itself.

Comment: Awesome riddle! This is such a weight off my mind. I've been trying to work this one out since I saw it pop up yesterday.

Comment: @NonsenseSynapse thanks! I was starting to wonder if it's too boring as there are not many attempts, then yours pop up.  I wonder what you've guessed thou, before going into the correct answer above

Comment: @Alex I think it was less of people not wanting to guess, and more of your riddle having a specific enough solution that it's hard to have a guess that matches your criteria, but is still incorrect. As for my process, I had a piece of scrap paper written out with the numerical values of every letter, seeing if there was a pattern there. Before your hint, I was comparing "Father" to "Mother" and "Brother." Since they all contained "ther," I figured there had to be something distinguishing "Fa" from "Mo/Bro, "and also unified "Mo/Bro."

Comment: Ah I see, thanks!  Gave me an idea on how should I create riddle as well as the approach solving one.